# general question about node_modules and security

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Can't find anything on this online and might be a non-issue, but I figured I'd ask here to make sure.

We run the Wordfence security plugin on a bunch of WordPress sites and have recently seen this "critical issue" reported:

```
Filename: wp-content/themes/theme-name/node_modules/webpack-assets-manifest/test/fixtures/client.js
File Type: Not a core, theme, or plugin file from wordpress.org.
Details: This file appears to be installed or modified by a hacker to perform malicious activity. 
If you know about this file you can choose to ignore it to exclude it from future scans. 
The matched text in this file is: require('./Ginger.jpg');

The issue type is: Backdoor:PHP/req_img.3645
Description: A backdoor known as req_img
```

Now first of all that doesn't look like a backdoor to me, especially since node_modules contents aren't executed unless I run npm (or yarn), as far as I understand. Is this more serious than I think?

Secondly, when running npm/yarn on the server, the node_modules folder has chmod 775 (drwxrwxr-x) by default. Is it okay to leave it like that or should we take any action?

Comment: It is about this package. https://github.com/webdeveric/webpack-assets-manifest/tree/master/test/fixtures Maybe you can download the original package and compare the contents of the package to see if there are suspicious differences.

Comment: To me it looks like WordPress WordFence does not not know about the node_modules in the theme folder and just notify that there is a suspicious require to an image. And they ask you to check if it is safe.

Comment: I have tried to find any information about "Backdoor:PHP/req_img.3645" without success. Did you find any more information about this type of backdoors?

Comment: No, couldn't find anything else on this. Everything is the same as on the official GitHub repo, so I assume a false alarm. But as stated it brought up the question of general security regarding node_modules.